# Is there a way to use Turf.js Along() from a point on a polyline?

Tags: polyline, turfjs

I need to find the coordinates of a point on a polyline at a certain distance from another one.

This is similar to Turf.js along() method, except that along() starts computing from the polyline start point.

So I am looking for along(), but from a given point on a polyline.

Answer (score 3):

You need a few steps to achieve what you need.

1. Split the polyline into 2 parts at a specified vertex.
2. If the second part is used, use it normally.
3. If the first part is used, reverse the coordinates, then use it.

Here is the proposed code:

```
// original polyline
var line = turf.lineString([[-83, 30], [-84, 36], [-78, 41]]);

// split point (second vertex, [-84, 36])
var splitter = line.geometry.coordinates[1];

// split the original polyline
var split = turf.lineSplit(line, splitter);

// prep the first portion (reverse the coordinates)
var part1 = split.features[0];
part1.geometry.coordinates = part1.geometry.coordinates.reverse();

// the second portion
var part2 = split.features[1];
```

Then you can use

```
var distance = 0.5; //unit: meters
turf.along(part1, distance, {units: 'meters'});
```

or

```
turf.along(part2, distance, {units: 'meters'});
```

**Runnable code**

```js
var line = turf.lineString([
  [-83, 30],
  [-84, 36],
  [-78, 41]
]);
var splitter = turf.point(line.geometry.coordinates[1]);
var split = turf.lineSplit(line, splitter);

var part1 = split.features[0];
var part2 = split.features[1];

// part 2
var distance = 0.5;
var p2 = turf.along(part2, 0.5, {
  units: 'meters'
});

console.log("P2 (x,y) on part2: " + p2.geometry.coordinates);

// part 1
console.log("Original list of (x,y) of part1: " + part1.geometry.coordinates);
part1.geometry.coordinates = part1.geometry.coordinates.reverse();

console.log("List of (x,y) of part1: " + part1.geometry.coordinates);
```

```html
<script src='https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>
```